# 'LXC launch' gives 'Error: Failed instance creation'

Tags: ubuntu, ros, lxc

Trying to run this:

```
ros@ros-Virtualbox:/$ sudo lxc launch -p row ubuntu:20.04 turtlebot
Creating turtlebot

Error: Failed instance creation: Failed creating instance record: Failed initialising instance: Failed getting root disk: No root device could be found

ros@ros-Virtualbox:/$
```

But the above error is shown.

- Made sure LXC was installed
- Removed version from 'ubuntu'; `ubuntu:20.04`

Comment: Seems like the profile `row` doesn't have a root disk in it. You can verify if the profile that you are trying to use via `-p` option which is `row` has any `root:` device in it by executing `lxc profile show row`. If it doesn't list any `root:` device then you need to either add a root device or create one. Please refer https://linuxcontainers.org/lxd/docs/master/profiles/

Comment: Refer: https://discuss.linuxcontainers.org/t/failed-detecting-root-disk-device/9597/25